# Quarkus Response type can´t receive a parameter

Tags: java, rest, quarkus

Is there any way in Quarkus where I can define the Response object with an actual object? I can only manage to use it like this at the moment:

```
Response findAll();
```

Basically what I want to achieve is something similar with Spring ResponseEntity:

```
ResponseEntity<List<SampleResponse>> findAll();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use RESTEasy Reactive, you can `org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.RestResponse` which has an API almost identical to `javax.ws.rs.core.Response`.

See the [documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy-reactive#manually-setting-the-response) for more details.

Comment: Im not sure if what im going to say makes sense but since Im not making use of Reactive cant I simply use the ResponseEntity from Spring? I already checked and I can use that dependency in Quarkus with no problem with quarkus-spring-web.

Comment: You can only use `ResponseEntity` in Spring Web controllers, not JAX-RS resources

Comment: Im quite new to Quarkus so I dont quite understand how that will afect my development but going back to the RestResponse dependecy, is it safe/good to use on any kind of endpoint (rective or not reactive)?

Comment: Yes, it is the same as using `Response`. So if you use `quarkus-resteasy-reactive` (or one of the dependencies that use it), you can use `RestResponse` wherever you like.

Comment: Great, thanks for the tips :D I will give it a go!

Comment: You are welcome. If this works for you, please accept the answer so future readers will know it works

Comment: I changed one of the endpoints to return the RestResponse and got this error:java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.jboss.resteasy.core.providerfactory.ResteasyProviderFactoryImpl cann
ot be cast to class org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.jaxrs.RuntimeDelegateImpl (org.jboss.resteasy.core.providerfactory.ResteasyProviderFactoryImpl and org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.jaxrs.RuntimeDelegateImpl are in unnamed mo
dule of loader io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader

Comment: What does the code look like?

Comment: I just figured it out... I didnt know this before but the order of POM dependencies matter and when I changed them it started working...